# Html Select tag with numbers end to a variable JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl, html-select

I have a number (0 - 10) stored in a variable. I want to display a select tag in my JSP page, which would start from 0 and end to that number. How can I do that? For example, if number=4, then the select tag would have options 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: what have u tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSTL tag [`<c:forEach>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) is your choice!

```
<select>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${number}">
        <option><c:out value="${number}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSTL `c:foreach` tag.  Import the JSTL core taglib, and write the following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><&lt;:forEach&gt; Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select>
            <c:foreach var="i" begin="0" end="${limit}">
                <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
            </c:foreach>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Make `limit` a request attribute, and fill in the `<form>` tag as you need it.